# Why is $\ln N - \ln(N-1) = \frac1N$ for large $N$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

May I ask why is $\ln N - \ln(N-1) = \frac1N$ for large $N$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

You can get quite far with just algebra:

$$\begin{align}
\ln N - \ln (N-1) & = \ln N - ( \ln N + \ln (1-1/N)) \\
& = -\ln (1-1/N)
\end{align}$$

using the laws for addition of logarithms. Now you can use the [Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series):

$$-\ln(1-x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots$$

to get

$$-\ln(1-1/N) = \frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{2N^2} + \cdots$$

so that $\ln N - \ln (N-1)$ is, for large $N$, equal to $1/N$ plus a correction term of order $O(1/N^2)$.

Comment: @Mathlover This was used by Euler when studying $\gamma$ and Harmonic numbers. He saw that $\log \left(1+\dfrac 1 n \right)\sim  H_n $

Answer (score 10):

The two sides of your equation are never exactly equal. But their ratio tends to 1 as $N$ tends to infinity. This is because the derivative of the $\ln$ function at $N$ is $1/N$, so that is approximately the amount by which the function changes between $N-1$ and $N$.

Comment: And the increment 1 is small when $N$ is large.

Comment: @TonyK This is a nice approach. Kudos!

Comment: Also, think about $\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(ln N - ln(N-1)\right)$. It's 0, which is also $\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)$.

Answer (score 6):

$\small \begin{eqnarray} \ln(n) - \ln(n-1) &=&\ln(n)-\left( \ln(n)+\ln({n-1 \over n}) \right) \\ 
 &=& -\ln(1-1/n ) \\ 
&=& 1/n + 1/n^2/2+1/n^3/3+... \end{eqnarray} $

The latter approximates $\small 1 / n $ when *n* increases without bounds.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x-\ln(x-1)}{1/x} &= \lim_{x\to\infty}x(\ln x-\ln(x-1))\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)^x\right)\\
&=\ln e\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
Where $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)^{x-1}\left(1+\frac 1{x-1}\right)=e\cdot 1=e$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the exact value (I'm surprised it hasn't been mentioned so far, though it's implicit in the "it's the derivative" answer):

$$\begin{align}
\ln N &= \int_{1}^{N} \frac1x \, dx \quad \text{ and }\\
\\
\ln (N+1) &= \int_{1}^{N+1} \frac1x \, dx, \quad \text{ so }\\
\\
\ln (N+1) - \ln N &= \int_{N}^{N+1} \frac1x \, dx
\end{align}$$

Now, as $\frac1{N+1} \le \frac1x \le \frac1N$ for $N \le x \le N+1$, clearly we have

$$ \frac{1}{N+1} \le \ln(N+1) - \ln N \le \frac1{N}$$

Calculating the integral more precisely would give a more precise estimate of $\ln(N+1) - \ln N$.

Answer (score -2):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln n-\ln(n-1))=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\ln \frac{n}{n-1}\right)=\ln\left(\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n-1}\right)=\ln 1=0 $

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$

Hence , for large $n$ both $\ln n-\ln(n-1)$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ tends to zero .

Comment: For example, 1/x^2 does not look like (tend to) 1/x as x->infinity, even though they both tend to 0. However 1/x - 1/x^2 -> 1/x as x-> infinity. So there are two things going on here. Indeed lnN - ln(N-1) -> 1/N as N -> infinity (which is (different, and) stronger than just saying both sides tend to 0)

Comment: @Adam: I just wanted to mention that because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757), so the site behavior you experienced was normal.